# Why do objects following a path have a random drastic rotation?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

[image]

For this blend file I have a curve with many vertices that form a consistent smooth path. I'm animating a walking spider along the curve, it follows the curve perfectly position-wise, and "follow curve" is also checked to enable rotation. I also pressed "alt+g" to make sure it's position is at its default and everything is set how it should be.

But, for seemingly no reason whatsoever, between literally just one frame and another, there are these extremely intense changes in rotation that make the spider rotated completed off its axis for the rest of the path animation as it moves. When I played with the curve in edit mode, I have no idea why this happens, but tiny slight changes in a vertex location have this extremely devastating effect on the spider's rotation to the point where it just flips completely around it's axis completely. How do I prevent this sort of thing from happening? It's a completely smooth curve, all of the arrows have a smooth transition in their orientation from one another, I see no reason for this. A similar thing occasionally happens when I'm rigging bones.

Comment: You can upload pictures directly to the site or if you're having trouble, post links in the comments and someone will edit your post with the pics.
Upload blend file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Why would stack exchange have their upload service on a completely different area of the site? I'd never guess where that was in a million years.

Comment: Stack exchange is not a file server.  It has peripheral sites to host significant data other than text.
https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your tilt rotation (in your curve) in vertices that you find weird rotation of your object

in curve edit mode:
Alt + t
to clean

Ctrl + t
to "play" with your tilt rotation

you can even do this with all vertices selected or part of them

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. On the curve properties menu (Object data properties), Shape > Twist method, changing it to Z-Up instead of Minimum fixed it for me, just tweak that or the Smooth option too and see if it works for you.